# show/hide toggle in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have 4 cards in my html page,i need to show mattoolitip on click function to show/hide mattooltip in Angular . I was calling same method in all tooltip but for all it is displaying the first mattooltip data only.

app.component.html:

```
<div class="card-body">
<div class="ml-auto p-2 pointer"
                     matTooltip="Here you can see the one"
                     matTooltipPosition="above" (click)="toggleShowTooltip()">
                  <i class="info-icon" ></i>
                </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="card-body">
 <div class="ml-auto p-2 pointer"
                     matTooltip="Here you can see the two"
                     matTooltipPosition="above" (click)="toggleShowTooltip()">
                  <i class="info-icon" ></i>
                </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="card-body">
 <div class="ml-auto p-2 pointer"
                     matTooltip="Here you can see the three"
                     matTooltipPosition="above" (click)="toggleShowTooltip()">
                  <i class="info-icon" ></i>
                </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="card-body">
 <div class="ml-auto p-2 pointer"
                     matTooltip="Here you can see the four"
                     matTooltipPosition="above" (click)="toggleShowTooltip()">
                  <i class="info-icon" ></i>
                </div> 
 </div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
  @ViewChild(MatTooltip) tooltip: MatTooltip;
   toggleShowTooltip(): void {
   this.tooltip.show();
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: hi @Aruna,but you should first show your "try", or at least say what specific doubt you have doing your function.

Comment: when i click on fourth tooltip it should show fourth tooltip data.

Comment: You can try something like 

 <mat-card
    #tooltip="matTooltip"
    [matTooltipShowDelay]="1000000000"
    matTooltip="Info about the action"
    matTooltipPosition="above"
    (click)="tooltip.show(0)"
  >
    My card
  </mat-card>

Which is not elegant at all...but you get the idea.
In order to have it working with ViewChildren, you need to use...well, ViewChildren instead of VIewChild. Or id your divs and use multiple ViewChild's.

Comment: I have left a response below which potentially will work for you. As I see you are a new contributor in here, please, mark the response as correct if its correct, in order to give gratitude and points to the person who helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use ViewChild in this case because it is not as you expected, also there are 4 tooltips.

Easier way is to use the Angular Template References.

```
    <div #tooltip="matTooltip" matTooltip="Text here" (click)="tooltip.toggle()">
       <i class="info-icon"></i>
    </div>
```

Also, you can call a method and pass the reference to it and from TS just call the toggle or any other further actions, like `(click)="toggleShowTooltip(tooltip)"` and in the code add the param and its type in order to use it.

Further reference/example in doc:
https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples#tooltip-manual